# Sharepoint read only with password to read and write on sharedrive. Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

So whenever I want to save the file from the sharepoint with save macro that is password protected that can be and should be open in read only mode, file is saved in the right direction on the sharedrive etc etc. but when I want to save the file that macro created with ctrl + S this leads me to save as window.

I have tried setAttr, .changefileaccess to xlreadwrite, access mode to exclusive on .saveas

I think I miss the part when I need to provide current password to save unlocked version in other direction.